# Batch- if command and "check internet connection"

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, connection

I have problems with my router when downloading through steam and other programs, such as the internet losing connection with the router. I cant plug my pc to my router using cable so i made a solution: 
and the other one
\Every X secounds disconect and connect to internet

But the problem is i want to make it more efficient so i would like a command that does this:

:a
\Check connection 
\if connected then goto a
\if noconnection disconect and connect to internet

i get problems with check connection command as its does not move on to the if

Please help and thanks for your time

Comment: Sorry about my grammar, im very tired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will `ping www.google.com` and if there is a response then `goto :a`, if not connected then it will `goto :Disconnected`.

The `findstr` will look for the `TTL` (Time to live) in the ping output. Great little trick that can be applied to multiple situations.

```
ping -n 1 www.google.com | findstr TTL && goto a
ping -n 1 www.google.com | findstr TTL || goto Disconnected

:a
REM Your connected script here

:Disconnected
REM Your disconnect / reconnect script here
```

You could also condense this to the below. As the script will continue if it does not `findstr TTL` or skip to `:a` if it does

```
ping -n 1 www.google.com | findstr TTL && goto a
REM Your disconnect / reconnect script here

:a
REM Your connected script here
```

Comment: Thank you mate, you are the best.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I made:

```
@echo off 
:b
cls
:a
color 0A
ping -n 1 192.168.0.1 | findstr TTL && goto a
ping -n 1 192.168.0.1 | findstr TTL || goto Disconnected

:Disconnected
color 0C 
echo.
echo        //_No_internet_connection_\\ 
echo.
echo              //_Disconnecting_\\
netsh wlan disconnect
timeout /t 1
netsh wlan connect virginmedia8960851
echo.
echo             //_Connecting_\\
echo.
timeout /t 6
goto b
```