# Detect connection lost with network device and stop application

Tags: batch-file, cmd, internet-explorer-11, ping, network-connection

I would like to create a batch app which is pinging constantly my network device.
Once Result changes into not found it should stop a certain application or my internet explorer.

How do I start with this?

I know i can ping my device with ping 192.168.0.1 -t constantly but how to stop the application with the result ?

Thanks in advance,

Regards,
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I have answered this one previously with a nice little batch file.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38088062/5552766)

The modification you need to make the above answer work would be:

```
:a
ping -n 1 www.google.com | findstr TTL && goto a
taskkill /IM <Your Task Name>
```

This will loop until the connection fails, then end script. You can add another `goto a` and make it loop again

- `ping` checks the connection between you and the location provided
- `-n 1` number of times to check (1)
- `|` pipes the result to the next command
- `findstr TTL` Find String, finds a string (TTL - Time to live) in the output

Live ping: `Reply from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=54`

Dead ping: `Reply from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Destination host unreachable.`

- `&&` Continue with command if previous command completed. Same as doing `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1`
- `goto a` a simple jump to a label (:a) in the script

Comment: 'what does the findstr TTL && got a' means.
Thanks btw

Comment: Edited the answer for a thorough explanation for you.

Comment: This is perfect when I startup the application but how do I perform a check during the use of the app ? How to make a while loop actually?

Comment: If you launch the app with the same powershell, you can't. You will need to have a second batch and call on that.

Comment: Same batch, not powershell, sorry.

Comment: So I can start actually another batch with the first batch file and let the other one check if network is still steady and if not kill the application...

Comment: Correct. Just do `start C:\Temp\PingCheck.bat` in your first batch file and it will then run this one on its own.

Comment: Thanks a lot Drew Lean

Comment: so what I did is next :
start "C:\Temp\PingCheck.bat"
ping -n 1 www.google.com | findstr TTL && goto a
ping -n 1 www.google.com | findstr TTL || goto Disconnected

:a
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"-k http://www.google.com

:Disconnected
TASKKILL /F /IM iexplore.exe

And in pingcheck.bat :
ping -t  www.google.com | findstr unreachable || goto Disconnected
:Disconnected
TASKKILL /F /IM iexplore.exe

Comment: If you have 1 bat file that you run to do a lot of tasks, you add `start "C:\Temp\PingCheck.bat"` into it. That will launch a batch file and it will run by itself, not messing up your first batch.
Unsure what the problem would be that you are encountering.